# JavaScript - найти ключи, зная их значения

Tags: javascript, ооп

Как сделать так, чтобы эта функция возвращала массив с ключами. Вот код этой самой функции:

```
Object.prototype.getKeyByValue = function(value, objs) {
    if (!objs) objs = [];
    for (var prop in this) {
        if (this.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
            if (this[prop] === value) {
                return prop;
            } else if(typeof this[prop] === "object" && objs.indexOf(this[prop]) == -1) {
                objs.push(this[prop]);
                var res = this[prop].getKeyByValue(value, objs);
                if (res) return prop + "." + res;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Эта функция хорошо работает в этом примере:

```js
Object.prototype.getKeyByValue = function(value, objs) {
  if (!objs) objs = [];
  for (var prop in this) {
    if (this.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
      if (this[prop] === value) {
        return prop;
      } else if (typeof this[prop] === "object" && objs.indexOf(this[prop]) == -1) {
        objs.push(this[prop]);
        var res = this[prop].getKeyByValue(value, objs);
        if (res) return prop + "." + res;
      }
    }
  }
}

var foobar = {
  foo: 5,
  bar: {
    baz: 3
  } //для теста сделаем вложеный объект
}

document.write(foobar.getKeyByValue(3));
```

Однако когда появляется второй ключ с таким же значением, он не находится (понятно почему). Надо сделать так, чтобы `getKeyByValue` возвращал массив. Так как это можно реализовать?

Comment: делать результату рекурсии не return а push

Comment: лучше измени snippet так, чтобы воспроизводилась твоя проблема. А не как сейчас - когда все хорошо работает

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
Object.prototype.getKeysByValue = function (value) {
    let keys = [];
    for (let key of Object.keys(this)) {
        if (this[key] === value) {
            keys.push(key);
        } else if (typeof this[key] === 'object') {
            let keysInner = this[key].getKeysByValue(value);
            for (let keyInner of keysInner) {
                keys.push(key + '.' + keyInner);
            }
        }
    }
    return keys;
};

let foobar = {
    aaa: 7,
    bbb: 10,
    ccc: {
        ddd: 7,
        eee: {
            fff: 7,
            ggg: 10
        }
    }
};

console.log(foobar.getKeysByValue(7));
```